# Observing html text changes with mutationObserver

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I try to observe if the text in the HTML element is changing, so if certain text has appeared, it will display another element.

```
var travelarea = document.querySelector("#travelInformationStep");
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
    if(mutation.target.text === "Europe"){
     document.getElementById("terjer2").style.display = "block";
    }
  });
});
var config = {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true}
observer.observe(travelarea, config);
```

But I'm not sure is how should I check those changes in the if statement.

Comment: This will depend on the type of change you expect. If only elements with id are changing, you might want to check for those ids.

Comment: In console travelarea.innerText returns "Europe" but in the code it does not react when 

`if( travelarea.innerText === "Europe"){
     alert();
    }`

Comment: But you have in if statement `.text` not `.innerText`

Comment: `var travelarea = document.querySelector("#travelInformationStep");
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
   if( travelarea.innerText === "Europe"){ 
alert(); }
  });
});
var config = {attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true}
observer.observe(travelarea, config); `

This version does not alert also.

Answer (score 3):

Try to check target's **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**. If the use case requires to avoid checking hidden or other text content that is not rendered in the browser, but is present in the `mutation.target` you can use [**innerText**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) instead of **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)**

```js
var travelarea = document.querySelector("#travelInformationStep");
var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.target.textContent === "Europe") {
      alert('Text changed to Europe');
    }
  });
});

var config = {attributes: true,  childList: true,  characterData: true};
observer.observe(travelarea, config);

document.getElementById('changeText').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  travelarea.textContent = travelarea.textContent === 'Europe' ? 'random text' : 'Europe';
});
```

```html
<p id="travelInformationStep">Some text</p>

<button id="changeText">Change</button>
```